# Unknown module(s) in QT: core gui widgets

Tags: qt

I just installed Qt5.4.1 MSVC2013 on windows, and when I tried to build a project, I encountered an error like

```
Unknown module(s) in QT: core gui widgets.
```

Then I add a user environment variable path

```
D:\Program Files\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64;
```

but the problem still exests.

I search the internet but it seems no one ever gets similar problem... it really confuses me.

Comment: qmake had issues with spaces in paths in the past, not sure they’re fixed now. If in doubt, I’d try to install to d:\qt\5.4 instad of d:\program files\...

Comment: So maybe reinstall Qt to a path without space might fix the problem. I‘ll try...
By the way, when I #include <QApplication>, creator suggests that there's no such file. Could that be the problem with environment viriable?

Comment: Reinstallation fixed it. Must be the space.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/42811/qmake-error-unknown-module-s-in-qt-network-widgets-gui-core/2):

> Library paths are hard-coded into Qt at compilation time. You can change that by using qt.conf file. Search for one in your installation and see what it contains. The syntax for conf files is described in Qt documentation. The general advice is: **"never move a Qt installation"**.

Comment: But I just installed Qt and have never moved it.